# Highlight table rows that have max value in a specific cell

Tags: jquery

I have a table (#tbl_maxmark) like this:

[image: Sample Table]

The fist cell(td) of each row is an itemcode which may repeat over rows. I need to highlight one row for each itemcode which has highest value in third cell. This is what I tried:

var key,temp;

```
$('#tbl_maxmark').find('tr').each(function(){

    key=$(this).find('td').eq(0).html();
    temp=$(this).find('td').eq(2).html();
    
    $('#tbl_maxmark tr').each(function(){
      
      if($(this).find('td').eq(0).html() == key){
        
        if(parseINT($(this).find('td').eq(2).html()) > temp){
            $(this).addClass('highlight');
        }           
      }
          
    })
        

})
```

Comment: *"third cell"*? `A` is greater or lower than `31`? Please count the cells correctly since you decided to hide the headings from us. Also please create a [mcve]

Comment: Actually it is a marks table. 1st cell is paper code, 2nd paper name, 3rd external marks, etc. 'A' means absent which can be reckoned as zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working suggestion.

First, it uses an `.each()` loop over the table rows to get the highest "mark" for each "paper" and store it in an object.

Second, a `for in` loop cycles all the different paper/mark pairs to loop again all rows and add the `highlight` class at the right place.

Look for the comments below... Ignore the first part which only was to recreate your table.

```js
let data = [ { col1: "LBA103", col2: "something like a description", col3: "17", col4: "10", col5: "27", col6: "0", col7: "Fail", col8: "4/2013" }, { col1: "LBA105", col2: "something like a description", col3: "21", col4: "18", col5: "39", col6: "0", col7: "Fail", col8: "4/2013" }, { col1: "LBA106", col2: "something like a description", col3: "25", col4: "16", col5: "41", col6: "0", col7: "Fail", col8: "4/2013" }, { col1: "LBA103", col2: "something like a description", col3: "A", col4: "10", col5: "10", col6: "0", col7: "Fail", col8: "6/2014" }, { col1: "LBA105", col2: "something like a description", col3: "A", col4: "18", col5: "18", col6: "0", col7: "Fail", col8: "6/2014" }, { col1: "LBA106", col2: "something like a description", col3: "A", col4: "16", col5: "16", col6: "0", col7: "Fail", col8: "6/2014" }, { col1: "LBA103", col2: "something like a description", col3: "31", col4: "10", col5: "41", col6: "0", col7: "Fail", col8: "4/2015" }, { col1: "LBA105", col2: "something like a description", col3: "A", col4: "18", col5: "18", col6: "0", col7: "Fail", col8: "4/2015" }, { col1: "LBA106", col2: "something like a description", col3: "26", col4: "16", col5: "42", col6: "0", col7: "Fail", col8: "4/2015" }, { col1: "LBA103", col2: "something like a description", col3: "21", col4: "10", col5: "31", col6: "0", col7: "Fail", col8: "4/2016" }, { col1: "LBA106", col2: "something like a description", col3: "26", col4: "16", col5: "42", col6: "0", col7: "Fail", col8: "4/2016" }, { col1: "LBA106", col2: "something like a description", col3: "24", col4: "16", col5: "40", col6: "0", col7: "Fail", col8: "4/2017" }, { col1: "LBA203", col2: "something like a description", col3: "11", col4: "18", col5: "29", col6: "0", col7: "Fail", col8: "12/2013" }, { col1: "LBA206", col2: "something like a description", col3: "23", col4: "14", col5: "37", col6: "0", col7: "Fail", col8: "12/2013" }, { col1: "LBA203", col2: "something like a description", col3: "A", col4: "18", col5: "18", col6: "0", col7: "Fail", col8: "11/2014" } ]
data.forEach(function(item) {$("#tbl_maxmark").append($(`<tr><td>${item.col1}</td><td>${item.col2}</td><td>${item.col3}</td><td>${item.col4}</td><td>${item.col5}</td><td>${item.col6}</td><td>${item.col7}</td><td>${item.col8}</td></tr>`))})

// ============================================= Forget about the above... ;)

// An object to find the highest marks
let highestMarks = {}

// Loop through the table rows
$("#tbl_maxmark tr").each(function(index, row) {
  let paper = $(row).find("td").eq(0).text()
  let mark = parseInt($(row).find("td").eq(2).text()) || 0

  let currentValue = highestMarks[paper] || 0
  
  // Store the mark if higher than wht is already stored
  highestMarks[paper] = (currentValue < mark) ? mark : currentValue
})

console.log("Highest marks:")
console.log(highestMarks)

// For every highest mark
for (mark in highestMarks) {

  // Loop all rows again to add the class
  $("#tbl_maxmark tr").each(function(index, row) {
    if ($(row).find("td").eq(0).text() === mark && parseInt($(row).find("td").eq(2).text()) === highestMarks[mark]) {
      $(row).find("td").eq(2).addClass("highlight")
    }
  })
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 0.3em;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl_maxmark"></table>
```

Notice that the "LBA106" is highlighted twice because the marks are both highest.

Comment: Thank you very much brother. Your solution perfectly suits my needs .